# Colab: Google drive file stream access permission is a hassle. Is there a better way?

Tags: permissions, google-colaboratory, tedious

I use Google Colab extensively. In order to get an easy access to files in my Google drive, I mount the drive to the file system of the virtual machine that runs Colab. Like that:

```
from google.colab import drive as cdrive
cdrive.mount('/content/gdrive')
% cd /content/gdrive/'My Drive'/'Colab Notebooks'/my_directory
```

[image: Colab sessin. Each time]

In the beginning of **each session**, I need to give a permission to access my drive. In order to do that, I need to press 'Allow', copy a one-time-password and paste it to a dedicated text area. It's a bit tedious.

Is there a better way? can I give a permanent permission based on my machine? any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, we can access google drive with the `Mount Drive` button on the left menu bar.

[image]

Confirm the access Google Drive action.

[image]

Then it will be mounted to your Colab notebook.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any luck with doing this in python code rather than manually?

Comment: @Silviu  I don't find any better solution. The code on the question is the simplest way to connect to Google Drive but it requires some authenticate steps.